# How can I share a link to a folder on a Time Capsule drive?

Tags: finder, time-capsule, file-sharing

We have a Time Capsule in the office.  I'd like to share a clickable link to a specific folder on the Time Capsule with my fellow employees.  Is there any way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to email out a link to people and they can click the link at it will open a Finder window in the specified folder on the Time Capsule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

- afp://gator._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data/Test

It's general with the following terms....

- afp://**TimeCapsule**._afpovertcp._tcp.local/***Data***/*Test*

This would work for a Time Capsule with name **TimeCapsule** and a Folder *Test* inside the drive named ***Data*** (I added the emphasis for clarity - you'll want to simply send the link in plain text)

You can get this by dragging the folder to your Finder sidebar and then looking in the Info window for that item.